# How to import a tensorflow checkpoint to keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, checkpoint

Is there a way to import a tensorflow checkpoint to a keras model before starting the training, in order to do some changes to the model?

Comment: You should be able to define a custom callback (look into: `keras.callbacks.Callback`) and overload the method `on_train_begin`.

Comment: I saw that solution but it looks like importing doing training. I would like to import before, do some modifications and launch the training